Chrome Extension with WebPush
I'm busy following this guide by Google:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/functional-samples/cookbook.push
Obviously this is completely impractical for production use. It does not subscribe automatically - this is probably because there is no call to the subscribe function.
If I Click “service worker (Inactive)” on the extension to load DevTools for background.js, and then in dev tools fire the subscribe function... I get my subscription response! Great, but I wouldn't expect customers to have to follow these instructions, right.
So I try to add the call to the subscribe function at to the bottom of the service worker script, but I get this error when I reload the plugin:
AbortError: Failed to execute 'subscribe' on 'PushManager': Subscription failed - no active Service Worker
If I look at known working code, in a more typical code, I notice slight difference:
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(serviceWorkerReg){
    serviceWorkerReg.pushManager.subscribe(options).then(function(pushSubscription){
        // success 
    });
});

But with the chrome extension the service worker is initialised via the manifest.json, so things are a little different. So now in my service-worker.js file I have self as a reference to ServiceWorkerGlobslScope, and self.registration as reference to ServiceWorkerRegistration almost like above.
Their sample code is:
self.registration.pushManager.subscribe(options).then(function(pushSubscription){
    // success 
});

What you can see is missing here, is the navigator.serviceWorker.ready, and this is making all the difference. It appears to be also the reason why their sample involves you having to call the subscribe function from DevTools.
It tried self.ready but it returns undefined.
So the question is: when can I call the subscribe function from inside my service worker script file? At what point does the service worker become active? or when is the service worker ready?
